# Finding coordinates of best fit rectangle

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Input:  A,B,a,b - where A and B my width and height of the grid, and a,b - width and height of rectangle that i want to fit in. Then i'm given N - number of rectangles,that already fitted in grid. In the next N lines i am given coordinates of opposite diagonal verteces of each rectangle,for example for first rectangle,input will be (x0,y0) (x1,y1) and so on. These rectangles can overlap. And i need to find coordinates of opposite diagonal verteces of initial rectangle, such that it can be fit in the grid(we need to print maximal height)
**Example:**

```
9 5 2 4
2
1 1 3 4
1 1 6 2
```

Output will be: 6 0 8 5 [Picture of input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpNHE.png)
Can you please give me some hints? It seems that i need to use dynamic programming here

Comment: Can you explain one input-output case elaborately? Your diagram is kind of useless without any markers.

Comment: The width `a` is fixed (`=2`) and the height `b` should be maximal `>=4`, right?

Comment: @HEKTO yes, but in boundaries of grid

Comment: Interesting question, but I think - you could improve its phrasing... AFAIU your grid means that all rectangles corners are integers, and the new rectangle shouldn't intersect with all the existing ones. Also your picture should be inside of your question

Answer (score 0):

If to assume that all coordinates are integers, then you could consider all the possible rectangles with width `a` and height `>=b`, inscribed inside the boundary rectangle with width `A` and height `B` - it's easy to see that their number is `O(AB^2)`. You will need to check the intersection of each such rectangle with your `N` predefined rectangles. There are data structures like [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), which will allow you to do a single intersection test in `O(logN)` time.

In more general case you can use the [Plane Sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) approach, and it will be much faster. I'll describe it briefly here.

At first you need to sort all the `X`-coordinates you have - including coordinates of the boundary rectangle (you call it *grid*). Each element of this sorted array `S` should store the `X`-coordinate value itself together with the rectangle number it belongs to, and a flag, marking left or right side of this rectangle.

Now imagine a "sliding" rectangle `T` with width `a` and height `B`, located in extreme left position inside the boundary rectangle - its left side will have the `S[0].x` coordinate. You can find all the rectangles, intersecting with the rectangle `T` looking into the array `S` only - let's call this set of rectangles an *active set*. You need to find out if you have an empty space with height `>=b` in the intersection of `T` with the active set. Remember the maximal rectangle with width `a` and maximal height `>=b` (if it exists).

Shift the sliding rectangle `T` to the right until its left side reaches the `S[1].x` coordinate. Again, you can use the array `S` to find the active set, intersecting with the `T`, and perform the same *local* analysis as before. If you can find an empty space inside the sliding rectangle, compare it with already found one and remember the best result.

Continue this process until the sliding rectangle `T` reaches the right side of the boundary rectangle. Number of shifts here is `O(N)`, and the time complexity of this algorithm depends on how effectively you can find an empty space at each step. Many approaches are possible here - a simplest one will be based on sorting of `Y`-coordinates. Also you can represent the active set of rectangles using some data structure. I'm leaving this part to you.